# Use router-outlet from another template

Tags: angular

I've been struggling trying to call router-outlet in one component template, from another component template.

I set my main router-outlet in ***full-layout.component.html***

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet name='left'></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And in the same template I have the navigation menu with routerLinks

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/company']">Link</a>
</li>
```

Now what I want to achieve, is that I have routerLinks pointing to that main router-outlet but in different component.

So for instance, in this component ***mycomponent.component.html*** I want to have routerLink which points to the router-outlet in ***full-layout.component.html***:

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/other-component']">Link</a>
```

I have trying using the router-outlet naming

```
<router-outlet name="myRouter"></router-outlet>
```

, but every time I set 'outlet' key in routing module, my application turns to white screen without any errors. Is there any other way than using router naming? Although I'm not even sure if naming would solve my issue.

Comment: have you tried removing the name on the `<router-outlet>`.  The main `router-outlet` doesn't need to be named since it is the primary `router-outlet`.  Name is used for aux routes or a secondary `router-outlet`.